# Why does my java method excute lines after a return statement?

Tags: java, xml, methods, return, return-value

I am following a tutorial for xml parsing in Java (ThinMatrix's on . youtube) and am trying to understand how the code works, by stepping through it.

```
    private static XmlNode loadNode(BufferedReader reader) throws Exception {
        String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        if (line.startsWith("</")) {
            return null;
        }
        String[] startTagParts = getStartTag(line).split(" ");
        XmlNode node = new XmlNode(startTagParts[0].replace("/", ""));
        addAttributes(startTagParts, node);
        addData(line, node);
        if (CLOSED.matcher(line).find()) {
            return node;
        }
        XmlNode child = null;
        while ((child = loadNode(reader)) != null) {
            node.addChild(child);
        }
        return node;
    }
```

In this block, the first time that the first "if-statement" executes - ie the first time the parser reads a closing tag - the line "return null" is executed, and then the program jumps to the while statement at the bottom of the method.  I have not seen this behavior before - why is the program not exiting the method after the "return null" statement.

Comment: Run it through a debugger. There is a chance that, because you using recursion, the return statement *is* working properly and the code is screwing up somewhere else.

Comment: This question seems to be more of a debugging issue than a real question about the code, so it's still a learning opportunity, even if it's not strictly about code.

Comment: @computercarguy yes i was actually wondering if this was the correct place to ask this for that very reason - do questions thare more about clarifying misunderstandings and less about fixing code get removed?

Comment: @TylerGoodwyn, actually I was trying to head off people down voting the question, rather than giving you advice.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the program not exiting the method after the "return null" statement?

The *method* is exiting after the `return null` statement.  That is different than the *program* exiting.  In general, in recursive methods, there are multiple "copies" of the same method running at the same time (kind of inside of each other).  So, one of the inner function calls to `loadNode()` is exiting at the `return null;` statement, and that `loadNode()` call was being made from an "outer" method call at the `while((child = loadNode(reader)) != null)` statement.

Recursion can be a bit tricky :)

Comment: Yep - I had tunnel vision on that one call, forgot that it was technically still in the while loop - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your debugging break is on the "return null;" line instead of the IF statement above it, so you are not actually breaking on the first iteration through.  This means that when it returns the null, the debugger goes back to the line of code that called that instance of the method, which would be the WHILE line.

You might be able to verify this if there's something in "node" or by changing your debuggers breakpoint to the very first line of that method.

Comment: That is exactly what was going on...got it figured out now, thank you!

Comment: @TylerGoodwyn, don't forget to upvote any answers you like.  With your low rating, the "green check" to accept an answer might not show up right away, but you should click that next to the answer that actually answers your question, whether it's mine or not.